Best practice finding object from user input in Python list
I'm doing this when I need to find an object from a user input, and it works, but I'm curious if there is a "right way" or "best practice" for it:
class Car:
    def __init__(self, model, price):
        self.model = model
        self.price = price


cars = [Car("Fiesta", 5000), Car("Etios", 3000), Car("Clio", 2000)]

car_wanted = input("Car model you want: ")

# This... I want the Car object so I'm getting it from the list by using a
# list comprehension and getting the value at index 0, which would be the one
# that matches. I know this depends on not having duplicates, this is a
# simplified example, but I would normally put it on a list and check
selected_car = [c for c in cars if c.model == car_wanted][0]

Before I used to do "finder" functions like this, but it's pretty much the same:
def car_finder(car_wanted, cars):
    matches = []
    for c in cars:
        if c.name == car_wanted:
            matches.append(c)
    return matches

Is there a proper way to do this?

If you only want the first match, next(c for c in ...) rather than [c for c in ...][0] avoids iterating over the whole list and building a new one.

@jonrsharpe thanks, but its that how its normally done, or are you just proposing a way to optimize my code? I'm interested in knowing what is actually used in general

"Actually used in general" means a lot of crap code. Write concise and clear code instead. @jonrsharpe's suggestion is that.

if you just want the first match, then next(<genexp>) is used as well as just a for-loop, where instead of appending to a amathes list, you just return c instead of matches.append(c)... but both of your approaches are fine
